# SQL comparing each rows date with the past year

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database with order_date, product code, and customer like the example here:

| Index | code | customer | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CCC | C | 2018-01-01 |
| 2 | AAA | A | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | CCC | C | 2021-02-02 |
| 4 | CCC | C | 2021-03-03 |
| 5 | DDD | A | 2022-04-04 |
| 6 | FFF | F | 2023-05-05 |
| 7 | FFF | F | 2023-08-08 |

I need a query to list all orders, where in the last year before the order date there was no order with the same product code and customer. In this example the desired output would be:

| Index | code | customer | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CCC | C | 2018-01-01 |
| 2 | AAA | A | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | CCC | C | 2021-02-02 |
| 5 | DDD | A | 2022-04-04 |
| 6 | FFF | F | 2023-05-05 |

If you look at row with index no. 4 and 7, you can see that in the past year there is another row with the same code and customer.

How is this achievable in mysql?

Comment: Use common WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: Can you provide example SQL code? My problem is that with each row, a table needs to be checked that changes constantly with each row date. What I mean is if you look at row with index no. 3, we need to check every row with an order date between 2020-02-02 and 2021-02-02. Since there is no row in this time frame with the same code and customer, it is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
from (
  select *
    ,lag(order_date)over(partition by code,customer order by order_date) pdt
  from orders
  ) x
where pdt is null or order_date>DATE_add(pdt,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
order by code,customer,order_date
```

Upd1. Some explanation.
In internal subQuery we get previous order_date for every (code,customer) combination. If no previous order row, we get `null`

```
select *
  ,lag(order_date)over(partition by code,customer order by order_date) pdt
from orders
```

| Idx | code | customer | order_date | pdt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | AAA | A | 2020-01-01 | null |
| 1 | CCC | C | 2018-01-01 | null |
| 3 | CCC | C | 2021-02-02 | 2018-01-01 |
| 4 | CCC | C | 2021-03-03 | 2021-02-02 |
| 5 | DDD | A | 2022-04-04 | null |
| 6 | FFF | F | 2023-05-05 | null |
| 7 | FFF | F | 2023-08-08 | 2023-05-05 |

Then, in this subquery result, we check `pdt is null` - no previous rows in this order. If `pdt is not null` then compare previous order_date with current.

Comment: This seems to work. Can you explain how it works?